# Pandas fill incremental values for NA's according to another column in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with sessions for each user. One of the column is sessions till now. Some of these sessions have null values. I believe I could use fillna and transform methods to appropriately fill the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user': [A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C],  'sessions': [28, NaN, NaN, NaN , 32, NaN, NaN,NaN,12, NaN,15, NaN, 17,NaN]})
```

Expected Output DataFrame:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'user': [A, A, A, A, A, B, B, B, B, C, C, C, C, C],  'sessions': [28, 29, 30, 31 , 32, 9, 10, 11,12, 14,15,16,17,18]})
```

Tried Code:

```
df['sessions'] = df['sessions'].fillna(df.groupby('user')['sessions'].transform('mean'))
```

this works if I were to fill mean and this is as far as I could think. Please suggest a few approaches.

PS - The starting value of the session is not 1. I am doing it from a snapshot at some point of time. I do not have data going back till session number 1 for every user.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no mismatch between the not `NaN` values, you could do the following:

```
def fun(x):
    _, diff = (~x.reset_index().isna()).idxmax()  # find the absolute position of the first non NaN

    start = x[(~x.isna()).idxmax()] - diff  # find the start value

    result = pd.RangeIndex(start, start + len(x))  # generate range based on first value and length of group

    return pd.Series(data=result.values, index=x.index)  # return series


df['count'] = df.groupby('user').sessions.apply(fun)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   user  sessions  count
0     A      28.0     28
1     A       NaN     29
2     A       NaN     30
3     A       NaN     31
4     A      32.0     32
5     B       NaN      9
6     B       NaN     10
7     B       NaN     11
8     B      12.0     12
9     C       NaN     14
10    C      15.0     15
11    C       NaN     16
12    C      17.0     17
13    C       NaN     18
```

The first line of the function `fun`, is equivalent to:

```
diff = (~x.reset_index().isna()).idxmax()[1]
```

Basically find the index position in a normalized (starting from 0) index.

Comment: thanks! Can you please elaborate on how this works "_, diff = (~x.reset_index().isna()).idxmax()" ...A bit new to Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You may re-construct `sessions` by using groupby `cumcount` and `first`

```
s = df.groupby('user').sessions.cumcount()
s1 = (df.sessions - s).groupby(df.user).transform('first')

df['sessions'] = s1 + s

In [867]: df
Out[867]:
   user  sessions
0     A      28.0
1     A      29.0
2     A      30.0
3     A      31.0
4     A      32.0
5     B       9.0
6     B      10.0
7     B      11.0
8     B      12.0
9     C      14.0
10    C      15.0
11    C      16.0
12    C      17.0
13    C      18.0
```